# Indexing multilingual content in elastisearch

Tags: elasticsearch

What is the best way to index multilingual content (blog post) in [elasticsearch](http://elasticsearch.org/). Should I use a different index for each language? Different type or create multiple field?

Comment: Its better to use different types..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up using different types one for each language. This solution works pretty well.